# EntityFrameWork DataFirst and MVC Default Parameters Are Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project utilizing MVC4 and EF Data First in VS2012. The database has a table with a composite key comprised of two fields. When the edit action is called the optional default parameter id always has the value of zero and not the value of the selected record so nothing is returned from the DB. If the table has a single field primary key the parameter is populated correctly. I am not sure how to fix this, any suggest would help. Thanks

```
public class GamesController : Controller
{
    private Context db = new Context();

    //
    // GET: /Games/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var gms = from g in db.Games orderby g.Date, g.GameNumber ascending select g;
        return View(gms);
       // return View(db.Games.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Games/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Games games = db.Games.Find(id);
        if (games == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(games);
    }
```

**Adding a second parameter did not work.**

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0, int sid = 0)
    {
        Games games = db.Games.Find(id, sid);
        if (games == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(games);
    }
```

**DatabaseTable**

```
[Games]
GameNumber (PK, int not null)
Date (date, not null)
HomeTeamId (FK, int , not null)
AwayTeamId (FK, int , not null)
HomeTeamScore(int, null)
AwayTeamScore(int, null)
FieldId(FK, int, null)
GameType(nvarchar(15), null)
Season_Id(PK, FK, int, not null)
CreateDate(date, null)
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
namespace RetryMVC1
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Games",
            url: "Games/{action}/{id}&{sid}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Games", action = "Index", sid = "", gid = "" }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

}

**View**

```
@model RetryMVC1.Models.Games

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Games</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GameNumber)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HomeTeamId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomeTeamId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeTeamId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AwayTeamId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AwayTeamId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AwayTeamId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HomeTeamScore)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomeTeamScore)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeTeamScore)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AwayTeamScore)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AwayTeamScore)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AwayTeamScore)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FieldId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FieldId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FieldId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GameType)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GameType)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GameType)
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Season_Id)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**This is the view in question**

```
@model IEnumerable<RetryMVC1.Models.Games>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HomeTeamId)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AwayTeamId)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HomeTeamScore)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AwayTeamScore)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FieldId)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GameType)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HomeTeamId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AwayTeamId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HomeTeamScore)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AwayTeamScore)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FieldId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GameType)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: I know it's obvious but do you pass any arguments to `public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0, int sid = 0)`, or you have an actual record where `id = 0` and `sid = 0`? And you can also try `Games games = db.Games.Where(g => g.id = id && g.sid = sid).ToList()`;

Comment: @Leron That is my exact issue I could not figure out how to pass the arguments to the action. I am currently trying @DarthVader suggestion of adding a second parameter to the route config file. By the way I tried your query suggestion but modified it a bit.    `Games games = db.Games.Where(g => g.Season_Id = id && g.GameNumber = sid).ToList();`  I get the following error `"Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'"`

Comment: So I added a new route to RouteConfig and the parameters still are not passed. `So I added a new route to RouteConfig and the parameters are still not passed. ` routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Games",
                url: "Games/{action}/{id}/{sid}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Games", action = "Index", sid = "", gid = "" }
            );`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you should use `==` instead `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the second parameter to your route config.

Comment: I will see if adding a second route will work.  `routes.MapRoute(  name: "Games",url: "Games/{action}/{id}-{sid}",defaults: new { controller = "Games", action = "Index", id = 10, sid = 4 }
            );`

Comment: So I added a new route to RouteConfig and the parameters are still not passed. `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Games",
                url: "Games/{action}/{id}/{sid}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Games", action = "Index", sid = "", gid = "" }
            );`

Comment: can you post how you create link?

Comment: The link is created through a view, I updated the original question with the new route and view.

Comment: After reading your response for the hundredth time it occurred to me I was looking at the wrong view. The parameters are passed from the index view not the edit view. I updated the index view with `@Html.ActionLink("MyEdit", "Edit", new { id = item.Season_Id, gid = item.GameNumber})` and now see the parameters passed to the controller. Now all that is left is to get the database query correct.

Comment: Fixed by adding the new route and changing the action link to `@Html.ActionLink("MyEdit", "Edit", new { gid = item.GameNumber, id = item.Season_Id})`

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.